# issue with variable in strpos()

Tags: php

This code work just fine;

PS: this is just an example( I can't post what I'm working on,still an active project)

```
$string1 = 'hello its a me';
$string2 = 'hello its a me';
if (strpos($string1, 'hello it's a me') !== false) 
 {
    //do something
// this work just fine      
 }
```

but if I changed the actual string with the variable it doesn't work for some reason.

```
$string1 = 'hello its a me';
$string2 = 'hello its a me';
if (strpos($string1, $string2) !== false) 
 {
    //do something
   // this doesn't work!!   
 }
```

Comment: You have to escape the (') in the string2 variable

Comment: Amazing that _any_ of those work. Shouldn't the unescaped `'` be a compilation error in both cases?

Comment: What is your actual code? Neither of these would work.

Comment: I can't post the code, and the problem is not in the string because I took the same string that's working just  and put it in a var and it didn't work

Comment: So you're saying you have _some code_ that for _some reason_ does not work and you cannot show us your _actual_ code. How do you expect us to help?

Answer (score 0):

Escape the quotes like in string 1 or using double quotes like in string 2:

```
$string1 = 'hello it\'s a me';
$string2 = "hello it's a me";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `'` as a speech mark and an apostrophe, which is making the PHP script confused, it's sorta like you doing this
`$string1 = "Hello, it"s a me";`, can you see how that's confusing, as there are 3 speech marks? There are 2 possible solutions to this.

1. Escape the quotation mark with \
`$string1 = 'hello it\'s a me';`

2. Replace the outside speech marks with double quotes
`$string1 = "hello, it's a me";`